# Spring security remember-me not working properly, database table is not working properly

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, remember-me

After setting up spring security remember me (Persistent Token approach), the data of the user is stored into the database ('persistent_token' table). And I can see 'SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE' in my browser. After restarting the server, I refresh my and the same user is logged in. But, While same user is logged in again, his data should be updated. But, it is not updated, it is inserted into database. So, one user has multiple values in that table. 
my applicationSecurity.xml is,

```
 <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ADMINISTRATOR')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:remember-me
              token-validity-seconds = "1209600"
              data-source-ref = "dataSource"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
   <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
 </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

My entity class,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persistent_logins")
public class RememberMeToken implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Id
@Column(name = "series")
private String series;

@Column(name = "token")
private String token;

@Column(name = "last_used")
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;

public RememberMeToken(){
}

public RememberMeToken(PersistentRememberMeToken token)
{
    this.username = token.getUsername();
    this.series = token.getSeries();
    this.token = token.getTokenValue();
    this.date = token.getDate();
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getSeries() {
    return series;
}

public void setSeries(String series) {
    this.series = series;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

}

implementing PersistentTokenRepository,

```
 @Repository
 public class PersistentTokenRepositoryImpl implements PersistentTokenRepository{

@Autowired
private RememberMeTokenRepository rememberMeTokenRepository;

@Override
public void createNewToken(PersistentRememberMeToken token) {

    RememberMeToken newToken = new RememberMeToken(token);
    this.rememberMeTokenRepository.save(newToken);

}

@Override
public void updateToken(String series, String tokenValue, Date lastUsed) {


    RememberMeToken token = this.rememberMeTokenRepository.findBySeries(series);
    if(token != null)
    {
        token.setToken(tokenValue);
        token.setDate(lastUsed);
    }
}

@Override
public PersistentRememberMeToken getTokenForSeries(String series) {

    RememberMeToken token = this.rememberMeTokenRepository.findBySeries(series);
    return new PersistentRememberMeToken(token.getUsername(),token.getSeries(),token.getToken(),token.getDate());        
}

@Override
public void removeUserTokens(String userName) {
    Iterable<RememberMeToken> tokens = this.rememberMeTokenRepository.findByUserName(userName);
    this.rememberMeTokenRepository.delete(tokens);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to give username and token unique attributes, that is the way you can ensure that only the unique row is inserted or else if the value is updated, and you can also check in createNewToken() method if the email is already inserted and if the email is not present then only you can insert that row, that way you will get single row for single email, hope this will help you, regards!